# How to display user input with a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the user input through the submit button.  The user will input tool types and then the first five inputs will be displayed in the li's.  Then as the limit of 5 tools is reached, another function prints 'Thanks for your suggestions'.  However, I can't get the function to print out any of the user input for suggested tools.  Could someone help me understand why they aren't printing out?

```
<script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js">

var i = 1;
var listItem = "";

function processInput() {

  if (i <= 5) {

      listItem[0] += 1;
      listItem = toolBox;
      var toolBox = "";
      alert("This is running");

      if (i == 5) {
          var resultsExpl = "Thanks for your suggestions";
    }
  }
  var backSubmit = document.getElementById("button");

  if (backSubmit.addEventListener) {
    backSubmit.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
  } else if (backsubmit.attachEvent) {
    backSubmit.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
  }

}
</script>


<div id="results">
      <ul>
         <li id="item1"></li>
         <li id="item2"></li>
         <li id="item3"></li>
         <li id="item4"></li>
         <li id="item5"></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
  </div>
  <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
          Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="toolBox"/>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id ="reset" onclick="resetForm()"/>Reset</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: I presume you're not using jQuery?

Comment: Note that you have: `<script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js">` which will cause the content of the script element to be ignored.

Comment: @RobG, I'm running the code through that external file.  Just put in all in together for the sake of space!  I should have taken that off for example's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wbof6vs5/5/) to your problem.

I have removed the button type as `submit` because in some browsers instead of calling the function `processInput` it will submit the form.

Here is my JavaScript that I changed,

```
   var count=1;
function processInput(){
    var tool = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
    document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
    if(count==5){
        document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions";

        document.getElementById("item"+count).innerHTML = tool;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("item"+count).innerHTML = tool;
        count++;
    }
}
 function resetForm(){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<ul><li id="item1"></li><li id="item2"></li><li id="item3"></li><li id="item4"></li><li id="item5"></li><p id="resultsExpl"></p></ul>';
}
```

The only change I made to your HTML code was to add `formId` as the `id` for your form.

```
<div id="results">
      <ul>
         <li id="item1"></li>
         <li id="item2"></li>
         <li id="item3"></li>
         <li id="item4"></li>
         <li id="item5"></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
  </div>
<form id="formId">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
          Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="toolBox"/>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id ="reset" onclick="resetForm()"/>Reset</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: So many edits lol. First it didn't input anything, now it replaces the 5th character and no alert, the reset button doesn't work. Le sigh, just saying. It's not about who answers first, it's about getting it right, preferably the first time.

Comment: @Jesse Well when my answer was not perfect I did left a "PS note" saying I'm still perfecting it. And the OP doesn't want to alert "Thanks for suggestions" as the OP wants it to print int the <p> tag with id "resultsExpl". The OP has not mentioned any concerns about resetting the form so I didnt worked for that part, but since you mentioned it I will create a function to reset the li

Comment: Ah i'm just giving you a hard time, you are fine bro ;)

Comment: @Jesse I wish stackoverflow can give us emoticons...Lol.... Updated the answer and now it can reset the form too.

Comment: Not overkill. Same quality as OP, you earned my thumbsup

Comment: @SaumilSoni, thanks for the help guys.  I've just started learning JS and this is my first use of StackOverflow.  So excuse my lack of description on the problem.  You guys were a great help, thanks again.

Comment: @Jesse ^ directed to you as well.

Comment: @SaumilSoni i forgot to add, what about adding a backward-compatible event listener for the 'click' on the submit button? (With an ID of button).

Comment: @SethSpivey what do you mean by backward compatible?

Comment: @SaumilSoni I'm assuming it means to allow the submit button work in older web browsers.  However, I can't see any issues as to why this wouldn't work in older versions.  Just disregard that... haha

Comment: @SethSpivey ya it is safe to assume this will work in old browser but if you want robust solution than maybe you should use jQuery. However, I wouldn't worry much for the current scenario...

Answer (score 3):

For me not much of this was working so I modified your code a bit to this working example. Each input fills in the `<li>` fields in order. On the 5th entry, you get alerted, and on the reset button the `<li>`'s are blanked out. Was not sure if this is what you were going for specifically but it sounded like it

```js
var i = 1;

function processInput() {
    if (i <= 5) {
        document.getElementById('item' + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById('toolBox').value;
        document.getElementById('toolBox').value = '';
        if (i == 5) {
            alert('Thank you for your suggestions');
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}

function resetForm() {
    while (i >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('item' + i).innerHTML = '';
        i--;
    }
    i = 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
          <ul>
             <li id="item1"></li>
             <li id="item2"></li>
             <li id="item3"></li>
             <li id="item4"></li>
             <li id="item5"></li>
          </ul>
          <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
      </div>
      <form>
          <fieldset>
            <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
              Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="toolBox"/>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" id ="reset" onclick="resetForm()"/>Reset</button>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to list some of the problems you have into your code:

1. Defining a `script` tag with the `src` attribute, and writing code inline, this will never work
2. Defining some global variables, and although this isn't a bug, it's a really bad design
3. Declaring a variable `listItem` as an empty string, and then using its 1st character to increment a `Number`, I don't realize exactly what you're trying to do here.
4. Then, you set an undefined/undeclared `toolBox` variable to the `listItem` string
5. And, afterall, you add a `click` event handler to the `submit` button,  but to an undefined callback

---

Well, since your code doesn't make much sense for me, but I think I got what you're trying to achieve, I've made an example of your code updated, and you can check the full commented code below:

```js
/* we encapsulate your hole code into an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)
   the goal here is to not polute the global scope, so the variable declarations reside inside it */
(function(d) {
  /* that's the counter you already had, I renamed it from i to item */
  var item = 1;
  
  /* we cache all the elements we're going to use here, by getting them by id */
  var txt = d.getElementById('toolBox'),
      btn = d.getElementById('button'),
      reset = d.getElementById('reset'),
      results = d.getElementById('results'),
      resultsExpl = d.getElementById('resultsExpl');
  
  /* we add the 'click' event handlers to our buttons
     it's better than puting directly inside the HTML, because it's a better design
     this approach is known as Unobstrusive Javascript */
  btn.addEventListener('click', processInput);
  reset.addEventListener('click', resetForm);

  /* your processInput function, with the same logic you had, but fixed */
  function processInput() {
    if (item <= 5) {
      /* here, we get the li tag by its id, concatenating the string 'item' to our variable item */
      var li = d.getElementById('item' + item);
      /* we must use the property textContent to change the text of the li
         and we get the user's input by getting its property value */
      li.textContent = txt.value;
      /* then, we increment our counter. the code below is the same as item += 1 */
      item++;
    }

    /* if the last item was inserted, we show our message */
    if (item > 5) {
      resultsExpl.textContent = 'Thanks for your suggestions';
    }
  }

  function resetForm() {
    /* to reset our form, firstly I loop through all the lis inside the div results */
    [].forEach.call(results.querySelectorAll('li'), function(el, i) {
      /* and I change each li textContent property to an empty string */
      el.textContent = '';
    });
    
    /* then, we set our input's value to empty, and we also reset our item variable to 1 */
    txt.value = '';    
    item = 1;
  }
})(document); /* I'm passing the document as a parameter, so I can use inside the IIFE as the variable d */
```

```html
<div id="results">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1"></li>
    <li id="item2"></li>
    <li id="item3"></li>
    <li id="item4"></li>
    <li id="item5"></li>
  </ul>
  <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
</div>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
      Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="toolBox" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little tidied up version of Saumil Soni's post:

```js
    var count=1;
    var done;
    function processInput(){
        var tool = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
        if (done!=1) {
          document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
        }
        if(count==5){
            if (done!=1) {
              document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions";
              document.getElementById("item"+count).innerHTML = tool;
              done = 1;
            }
        }else{
            if (done!=1) {
              document.getElementById("item"+count).innerHTML = tool;
              count++;
            }
        }
    }
    function resetForm() {
      location.reload();
    }
```

```html
<div id="results">
      <ul>
         <li id="item1"></li>
         <li id="item2"></li>
         <li id="item3"></li>
         <li id="item4"></li>
         <li id="item5"></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
  </div>
<form id="formId" onSubmit="processInput(); return false;">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
          Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="toolBox"/>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id ="reset" onclick="resetForm()"/>Reset</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```